# cast from jobject to jboolean loses precision

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to cast jobject to jboolean

```
    jmethodID mGet = env->GetMethodID(cJsonObjClass, "get","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");    
    jboolean val = (jboolean)env->CallObjectMethod(object, mGet , key);
```

getting this compile error:

> cast from 'jobject {aka _jobject*}' to 'jboolean {aka unsigned char}' loses precision [-fpermissive]

what does it mean and what to do?

Comment: _"I am trying to cast jobject to jboolean"_. Don't. A `jboolean` corresponds to the Java type `boolean`, which is a primitive, not an Object. You'd have to show more of your code for someone to be able to say what the correct approach would be (e.g. what's the type of `object`? what's the signature for the `Get` method? ...)

Comment: the object is json object
I solve it by replace the get method with getBoolean

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else who gets the error while using `CallObjectMethod`

```
error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'jboolean' (aka 'unsigned char') loses information
```

The correct way to call a method which returns a boolean ist to use `CallObjectMethod`

**So the answer here is:**

change

```
 jboolean val = (jboolean)env->CallObjectMethod(object, mGet , key);
```

to

```
jboolean val = (jboolean)env->CallBooleanMethod(object, mGet , key);
```